# What's the verb for news anchors talking in front of television?

Tags: word-request

What's the verb for news anchors talking in front of television?

Doing a news cast, reporting don't really meet the definition. For instance, reporting doesn't make sense if you want to use it for news anchors who are just speaking their mind like Tucker Carlson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK, we'd call this "presenting" (or if you wanted to be very specific even "newsreading" I suppose, though I'm not sure I've ever heard anybody say that).

I'm pretty sure the same verb applies in the same way in the US also.  I'm only slightly hesitant about that because here you don't hear the word "anchor" used in this context, I think the equivalent UK job title would be "presenter" or maybe "newsreader" -- so maybe the verb usage is subtly different in the US also.  I imagine you could say "anchoring" too.

Answer (score 0):

"News anchor" means "news presenter" and news presenters present news.